# Тернарный оператор и не ясная логика

Tags: java, return, тернарный-оператор

Какие-то сложности с тернарным оператором постоянно.

Таким образом оператор не работает.

```
Path.of(str).isAbsolute() ? System.out.println(Path.of(str).toAbsolutePath()) : System.out.println(Path.of(str));
```

А вот таким работает.

```
if (Path.of(str).isAbsolute()) {
System.out.println(Path.of(str).toAbsolutePath());
} else {
System.out.println(Path.of(str));
}
```

Получается, что он должен постоянно что-то возвращать, т.е. работать только с return ?

Хотя вот так получается норм?

```
System.out.println((Path.of(str).isAbsolute() ? Path.of(str).toAbsolutePath() : Path.of(str)));
```

А в чем собственно разница?
По факту логика идентична.

```
условие ? результат 1 : результат 2
```

т.е. полученный результат нужно обязательно чему-то присвоить или куда-то положить или вернуть, иначе тернарный оператор работать не может?

Comment: дело в том, что тернарный оператор возвращает boolean значение, а Path.of возвращает знаечение Path

Comment: Коротко - да, тернарный оператор требует выражение, которое вернет какое-либо значение `условие ? (выражение 1) : (выражение 2)`. Поэтому использовать его, к примеру, для вызова void-методов на типа `println` не получится.

Comment: SOUT(условие ? (выражение 1) : (выражение 2)) - проходит.

условие ? (SOUT(выражение 1)) : SOUT((выражение 2)) - не проходит


выражение - должно возвращать boolean, поэтому в sout его нельзя поставить, т.к. он по сути вообще ничего не возвращает, а выводит значение.



    Условие ? 

    1) выражение/результат (обязан вернуть boolean) :

    2) выражение/результат (обязан вернуть boolean)

Answer (score -1):

Тернарный оператор предназначен для работы одной переменной, которой по условию нужно присвоить два разных числовых значения. В этом случае операции сравнения и условных переходов не создаётся, в место этого применяется магия математики, и код на асме становится линейным. Адрес переменной может быть длинным, присвоение будет после математики. Пример:

```
x = a < 0 ? 1: 0;
```

Магия:

```
x = a >> ((sizeof a) * 8 - 1); // реально одна команда на асме!!
```

Однако вариант:

```
if (a < 0) x = 1; else x = 0;
```

Будет использовать операторы сравнения и условное исполнение в коде на асме, в обратную сторону оптимизация не работает.